# Visual Studio doesn't recognize new property in library hosted on NuGet/BaGet showing false Intellisense errors

Tags: c#, visual-studio, intellisense, visual-studio-2019

I developed a library, which is published on [BaGet](https://github.com/loic-sharma/BaGet) and used in one of my projects. When extending models in the library, I publish it to BaGet and then update the package in the referencing project using VS NuGet package manager. Somestimes, VS doesn't recognize those changes in Intellisense.

Example: I added a model field `AuthorUserName` in the library project and publish it:

```
public class VBLightForumThread {
    // Other fields
    public string AuthorUserName { get; set; }
}
```

After updating the new library in my project, intellisense show me an error when using the `AuthorUserName` property:

[image]

But the update was applied. In case of a Razor view, I could still start debugingg and the author name was shown in the rendered HTML. This could be even prooved in the Controller: VS show me an error, that would normally result in an compiling error. But I could compile and debug anyway. During debug it shows me the attribute value, altough VS still also shows the error that `AuthorUserName` doesn't exist:

[image]

#### Since it's annoying to have a lot of those false-errors in the VS error console: How can I fix this, so that VS show me those new properties in intellisense instead of throwing errors?

I already tried without success:

- Cleaning the solution
- Re-building the solution
- Restart Visual Studio

My installed version is Visual Studio 2019 Community 16.5.4. The only thing that helped temprorary was updating VS. In the situation above with the false error, I noticed an VS update. After the update, the error was gone. But now I extended a model of the library, and the error is still there. So it's not fixed by the update, but it seems that VS has some kind of Intellisense cache that got purged by the update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a workaround, it helped to close VS, then delete the `DesignTimeBuild` folder in `<ProjectName>/.vs/<ProjectName>` and re-open VS again. It took some time and the errors were gone.

Altought this works, I'd prefer some long-term solution that refreshes the cache automatically after updating NuGet packages. I assume that VS do this itself, because otherwise any modifications weren't shown after those updates. So please still post if anyone have a full solution for this problem.